# How can you use Ecto.Repo's preload function with a soft delete implemented

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I can query soft deleted, associated, database entries with Ecto.Query by doing something like this:

```elixir
query = from r in Resource,
        join a in Association, on: [resource_id: r.id]
        where: is_nil(a.deleted_at)

Repo.all(query)
```

This becomes tedious with some deeply nested associations. How can I use Ecto.Repo's built in preload function to query with a where clause that applies to all associations?

I would like to do something like:

```elixir
Repo.get(Resource, 1) |> Repo.preload(:association, where: [deleted_at == nil])
```

Is something like this possible, or is there another approach I can use to accomplish the same goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is, you should be able to do something like this:

```elixir
def list_resources() do
  from(r in Resource, preload: [foo: ^not_deleted(Foo), bar: ^not_deleted(Bar)])
  |> Repo.all()
end

def not_deleted(query) do
  from(q in query, where: is_nil(q.deleted_at))
end
```

Comment: do you know if it is possible to embed this behavior in every preload?